# How to construct and store the geopoint

Tags: google-app-engine, twitter-bootstrap-3, geolocation, webapp2, geopoints

Am working on GAE with python. How to construct and store the latitude and longitude using GeoPoint?

This is my DB

```
class Customer(db.Model):
    name = db.StringProperty()
    address= db.PostalAddressProperty()
    geopoint= db.GeoPtProperty()
```

My code

```
class AddCustomerHandler(BaseHandler):
    input_fullname=self.request.get('fullname')
    input_cusaddress=self.request.get('cusaddress')
    input_latitude=self.request.get('latitude')
    input_longitude=self.request.get('longitude')


    input_geopoint= GeoPoint(input_latitude, input_longitude)
    logging.info('****************** xxxx= %s', input_geopoint)

    newcustomer=Customer(name=input_fullname,address=input_cusaddress,geopoint=input_geopoint)
    newcustomer.put()
```

Am trying this code. But Am getting error. How to store this geopoint field?

Comment: What is the error you're getting?

Comment: input_geopoint= GeoPoint(input_latitude, input_longitude)
NameError: global name 'GeoPoint' is not defined.                                                    Am getting this error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> input_geopoint= GeoPoint(input_latitude, input_longitude) NameError: global name 'GeoPoint' is not defined.
> ```
>
> Am getting this error

You're getting that error because you don't have the module imported where `GeoPoint` is defined.

Add this import

```
from google.appengine.api import search
```

and then use like this

```
input_geopoint = search.GeoPoint(input_latitude, input_longitude)
```

Also see [the docs](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/search/geopointclass)